# How do I get the correct outputs for this chess board?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program of a chess board, When a user inputs an x and y value it will either output "black" or "white".

```
x = int(input("Please enter your (x) first number 1-8::"))
y = int(input("Please enter your (y) second number 1-8::"))

column = x % 2
row = y % 2


if column %2 == 0 and row %2 == 1:
  
    print("")
    print("white")


elif row %2 ==0 and column %2 == 1:
    print("")
    print("black")
```

Whenever i input 1 for "x" and 2 for "y" it outputs "black", great this is the correct output. But whenever i input some other numbers such as 2 and 2, it gives me a blank output. Whenever i input 1 and 4, it outputs "black" which the correct output should have been "white. How do i make it so that whenever user inputs two numbers ranging from 1 to 8, it outputs the correct colour tile? I am not trying to make the code more advanced but would appreciate some help!

This is the chess board i am basing the colours on.( Do not mind the text on the picture)

[image]

Comment: Your two conditions don't cover all possibilities. What condition is satisfied for the blank output you have found?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking at x and y separately, just check the sum.
If the sum is even, it's black, if the sum is odd, it is white.

I added a lookup of the name in a python dict, but you can just do it with `if` conditions if you prefer.

```py
x = int(input("Please enter your (x) first number 1-8::"))
y = int(input("Please enter your (y) second number 1-8::"))

color_picker = {0: "Black", 1: "White"}

if not 0<x<9 or not 0<y<9:
    print("Input valid number!!")
else:
    color
    print(color_picker[(x+y)%2])
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
if column %2 == 0 and row %2 == 1:
    ...

elif row %2 ==0 and column %2 == 1:
    ...
```

This covers the case where column is even and row is odd, and the case where row is even and column is odd.

But what about the cases where they are both even, or both odd?

Comment: That is part of what I actually need some guidance with. How do I code it so that my conditions cover all of the possibilities a user can input such as both odd, or both even, or even a number that exceeds the limit?

Comment: _or even a number that exceeds the limit?_ That depends on what you want to do in such a case.  Print an error message and prompt again?  Exit the program?  Use 8 by default?

Comment: using the print an error message and let the user input a new answer worked. But, how do I code it so that whenever the user inputs a number ranging from 1 to 8, no matter both odd or both even, it outputs the correct colour tile?

Comment: Look at @Techie_19's answer.  If the sum of row+column is even, the square is black, otherwise it is white.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input("Please enter your (x) first number 1-8::"))
y = int(input("Please enter your (y) second number 1-8::"))

column = x
row = y


if (column + row) %2 == 0:

    print("")
    print("black")


elif (column + row) %2 == 1:
    print("")
    print("white")

else:
    print("Input valid number!!")
```